# Spring Boot Controller function not terminating or returning when creating an apache poi workbook from MultipartFile

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi, multipartfile

So I am trying to send a file and an object to my Backend. I then use the Multipartfile to create an Apache Poi Workbook. Using apache's Iterator I loop over the file, extracting and saving what I need. That is working well (it even is saving the new data in the database), however the function when reaching the Return statement *is not returning*.

It seems to not terminate, since it is not returning a StatusCode, or an object (tried different Options, see below). My other controlerfunctions are doing fine, so I ensured, that my Code is reaching the return statement. I took lines out of the code until the problem is no longer occurring. It seems to occur when creating the workbook. I tried closing the Workbook. I even tried closing the Inputstream manually but the error is still occurring. I tried changing the return value (returning a Responseentity, returning a DTO, having a void function, and setting @HTTPResponseStatus), but that didn't change the behavior. When I took out the workbook all three methods worked. I tried different versions of apache poi (5.0.0, 4.0.0, 3.15). But still no return value.

This is my Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/trafficdata")
public class TrafficDataController {

@Autowired
TrafficDataRepository trafficDataRepository;

@PostMapping(value = "/filedata", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity addDataFromFile(@RequestParam("model") String model, @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) throws PermissionDeniedException, FileNotImportableException, DataKeyAlreadyTakenException, JsonProcessingException {
    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    if(!userDetails.isProfessor()){
        throw new PermissionDeniedException();
    }

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    FileTrafficDataInputDTO trafficDataInputDTO = mapper.readValue(model, FileTrafficDataInputDTO.class);

    if(trafficDataRepository.existsByDataKey(trafficDataInputDTO.getDataKey())){
        throw new DataKeyAlreadyTakenException(trafficDataInputDTO.getDataKey());
    }

    Workbook workbook;
    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
    String lowerCaseFileName = file.getOriginalFilename().toLowerCase();
    InputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = file.getInputStream();
        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream); //as soon as I take out this, it works
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new FileNotImportableException(file.getOriginalFilename());
    }

    try {
        //I tried something here inputStream.close();
        workbook.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /* working with the data */
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}}
```

these are my Maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>api-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Does anyone knows how to solve the issue and/or why exactly the issue is occuring?